# Is there any way to know Microsoft Windows Serial/Product Key Detail

Tags: windows

Is there any way to know Microsoft Windows 10 serial/product key detail like activation status, purchased date, owned by, and other details?

I purchased windows 10 professional license keys for my company according to the vendor one serial key is valid for 5 machines. i need to know activation status and detail against for each serial key.

PRODUCT KEY FORMAT: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fortunately I couldn't find Microsoft website or any tool to know the status or active licenses and finally, i called to vendor and gave my serials to get detail which i was not preferring to do.